# ¿Cómo puedo guardar correctamente un objeto dentro de una lista en Python 3.x?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo 2 clases distintas, una llamada `Registro` y la otra llamada `Proveedor`.

```
import msvcrt
import os
import clases.proveedor as registroP



class Registro():  

    def registroProveedor(self):
        os.system("cls")
        print("----------------------------------------------")
        print("         Supertienda LA COBANERITA")
        print("   --- REGISTRO DE NUEVOS PROVEEDORES ---")
        codProv = int(input("Código del proveedor: "))
        nitProv = int(input("NIT del proveedor: "))
        nomProv = input("Nombre del proveedor: ")
        direcProv = input("Dirección del proveedor: ")
        telProv = input("No. teléfono del proveedor: ")
        proveedor = registroP.Proveedor(codProv, nitProv, nomProv, direcProv, telProv)
                

        print("--- El registro del nuevo proveedor se ha realizado correctamente. ---")
        print("Presione 'Enter' para regresar...")

        print(registroP.lstProveedor)
        msvcrt.getch()
```

Y la clase modelo para proveedores es la siguiente:

```
lstProveedor = list()

class Proveedor:
    def __init__(self, codProv, nitProv, nomProv, direcProv, telProv):
        self.codProv = codProv
        self.nitProv = nitProv
        self.nomProv = nomProv
        self.direcProv = direcProv
        self.telProv = telProv
    
    def registrarProveedor(self):
        proveedor = (self.codProv, self.nitProv, self.nomProv, self.direcProv, self.telProv)
        lstProveedor.append(proveedor)
```

Y tengo dudas sobre almacenar el nuevo objeto *proveedor* en la lista *lstProveedor*, ya que al imprimirla en la función *registroProveedor* me devuelve una lista vacía [].

Comment: al hacer `registroP.lstProveedor` estas indicando que tu clase `Proveedor` tiene un atributo `lstProveedor` y no es así, en ningún momento declaras ese atributo

Comment: @Christian ¿cómo puedo indicar correctamente la impresión de la lista para saber si se están almacenando los objetos proveedor?

Comment: inicializa la lista dentro de tu *constructor*, asi `self.lstProveedor = []` y en tu método `registrarProveedor`, solo haces `self.lstProveedor  += (....)`

Comment: En ese caso debería enviar la lista también como parámetro en el método `registroProveedor` de la clase `Registro`

Comment: no hace falta hacer eso

Comment: Lo he cambiado tal cual, pero aún sigue mostrándome una lista vacía

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es claro y no lo noté y es que tu haces la instancia de clase y todo bien, pero en ningún momento llamas al método `registrarProveedor()` que es el encargado de agregar los datos a la lista. Por otra parte como dije en mi comentario estas tratando de imprimir un atributo que la clase no tiene, por lo que debes de inicializarlo en conjunto con los demás valores.

```py
class Proveedor:
    def __init__(self, codProv, nitProv, nomProv, direcProv, telProv):
        self.codProv = codProv
        self.nitProv = nitProv
        self.nomProv = nomProv
        self.direcProv = direcProv
        self.telProv = telProv
        self.lstProveedor = [] #aqui lo inicializamos con un valor vacio
    
    def registrarProveedor(self):
        self.lstProveedor+= (self.codProv, self.nitProv, self.nomProv, self.direcProv, self.telProv)
```

En la clase `Registro` solo nos hace falta llamar al método y listo!

```py
class Registro():  
    def registroProveedor(self):
        #...
        proveedor = Proveedor(codProv, nitProv, nomProv, direcProv, telProv) #creamos la instancia
        proveedor.registrarProveedor() #llamamos al método
                
        print("--- El registro del nuevo proveedor se ha realizado correctamente. ---")
        print("Presione 'Enter' para regresar...")

        print(proveedor.lstProveedor) #accedemos al atributo de la instancia
```

**probamos**

```
----------------------------------------------
         Supertienda LA COBANERITA
   --- REGISTRO DE NUEVOS PROVEEDORES ---
Código del proveedor: 10
NIT del proveedor: 99
Nombre del proveedor: christian naokiri
Dirección del proveedor: osaka
No. teléfono del proveedor: 999999999
--- El registro del nuevo proveedor se ha realizado correctamente. ---
Presione 'Enter' para regresar...
```

**resultado**

```
[10, 99, 'christian naokiri', 'osaka', '999999999']
```

Comment: Ya me devuelve los proveedores que fueron añadidos. ¿Cómo podría mostrar la lista completa de datos que posee `lstProveedor`?

Comment: recuerda que estas creando instancias de una clase por lo que el atributo solo pertenece a esa clase y no es de forma general

Comment: En ese caso, ¿cómo podria hacer una lista para almacenar múltiples objetos de una misma clase?. Por ejemplo, para luego almacenarlos en un fichero.

Comment: crea una lista totalmente aparte (fuera de todas tus clases) por ejemplo `info = []` y debajo del `print()` haces `info.append(proveedor.lstProveedor)`